# Return a Different Cell Value on First Non-Zero Instance

Tags: excel

I have a dataset like so:

```
    A   B    C     D    E   
1  Jan Feb March April May    
2   0   0    0     5   10
```

I want to return the month when the value in row 2 first stops being equal to 0 (April in this case).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
=INDEX(1:1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(2:2<>0,),0))
```

[image]

If you are using only 12 columns of data *(one for each month of the year)* then:

```
=INDEX(A1:L1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:L2<>0,),0))
```

will suffice.

Comment: You'll get a better performance by restricting the array (A1:G1 instead of 1:1).

Comment: @GregViers not on the outer index, but on the inner one yes, limit the range.  The outer will not effect the speed.

Comment: That being said it is easier to make the ranges referencing the same columns, as match is relative.